# Update Panel refresh by User control's button click event

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, updatepanel, postback

I have a UserControl "confirmResetBox" with OK and CANCEL buttons.

In a parent page, i have added Grid under UpdatePanel and i want to refresh the grid only when OK button is clicked and not when CANCEL button clicked.

Functionality is as below ,

1) Load grid with template fields.
2) User can modify data in template fields.
3) When user click on RESET button, it popup confirmation popup with OK and CANCEL buttons. 
4) Upon OK, it should refresh the page.

Below is the custom event in aspx.vb

```
  Private Sub ConfirmBoxReset_SubmitCleanup() Handles ConfirmBoxReset.SubmitCleanup

 End Sub
```

I am getting below error and unable to proceed. Looking forward right approach to implement this.
[image]

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="SignWorkflowContent" ID="content" runat="server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSATS" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnRSTS" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnReset" EventName="Click" />
            <%--<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnConfirm" EventName ="Click" />--%>
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div id="allContent" runat="server" class="content">
                <div id="GridViewCustomerDiv" padding-right="20px">
                    <table runat="server" id="TBCustomer" width="995px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="10">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div style="height: 100px; width: 1000;">
                                    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="109px" Width="1117px">
                                        <table id="Table1" style="width: 87%; height: 82px;" runat="server" colspan="0" rowspan="0">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="style57" bgcolor="#F4F4F4">
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblRegNo" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Reg No. :" Font-Names="Arial"
                                                        Font-Size="8.5pt" ForeColor="#666666" BackColor="#F4F4F4"></asp:Label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="style70">
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblRegNoVal" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Text="Label" Font-Names="Arial"
                                                        Font-Size="8.5pt"></asp:Label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td bgcolor="White" class="style65">
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="style60" bgcolor="#F4F4F4">
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblCustNo" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Customer No. :" Font-Names="Arial"
                                                        Font-Size="8.5pt" ForeColor="#666666" BackColor="#F4F4F4"></asp:Label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="style72">
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblCustNoVal" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Text="Label" Font-Names="Arial"
                                                        Font-Size="8.5pt"></asp:Label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td bgcolor="White" class="style68">
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="style63" bgcolor="#F4F4F4">
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblDocType" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial" BackColor="#F4F4F4"
                                                        Font-Size="8.5pt" ForeColor="#666666" Text="Doc Type :"></asp:Label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="style74">
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblDocTypeVal" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Names="Arial"
                                                        Font-Size="8.5pt" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td bgcolor="White" class="style65">
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="style56" bgcolor="#F4F4F4">
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial" BackColor="#F4F4F4"
                                                        Font-Size="8.5pt" ForeColor="#666666" Text="Status :"></asp:Label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="style71">
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblStatusVal" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Names="Arial"
                                                        Font-Size="8.5pt" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td bgcolor="White" class="style48">
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="style54" bgcolor="#F4F4F4">
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblCustNameLoc" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Customer Name (Local) :"
                                                        Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="8.5pt" BackColor="#F4F4F4" ForeColor="#666666"></asp:Label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="style73">
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblCustNameLocVal" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Text="Label" Font-Names="Arial"
                                                        Font-Size="8.5pt"></asp:Label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td bgcolor="White" class="style69">
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="style46" bgcolor="#F4F4F4">
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblDocID" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Doc ID :" Font-Names="Arial"
                                                        Font-Size="8.5pt" ForeColor="#666666" BackColor="#F4F4F4"></asp:Label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="style75">
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblDocIDVal" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Text="Label" Font-Names="Arial"
                                                        Font-Size="8.5pt"></asp:Label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td bgcolor="White" class="style48">
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="style56" bgcolor="#F4F4F4">
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblConsolidateType" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" BackColor="#F4F4F4"
                                                        Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="8.5pt" ForeColor="#666666" Text="Consolidate Type :"></asp:Label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="style71">
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblConsolidateTypeVal" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Names="Arial"
                                                        Font-Size="8.5pt" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td bgcolor="White" class="style48">
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="style54" bgcolor="#F4F4F4">
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblCustNameEng" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" BackColor="#F4F4F4"
                                                        Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="8.5pt" ForeColor="#666666" Text="Customer Name (Eng) :"></asp:Label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="style73">
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblCustNameEngVal" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Names="Arial"
                                                        Font-Size="8.5pt" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td bgcolor="White" class="style69">
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="style46" bgcolor="#F4F4F4">
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblDocIssuedCtry" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial"
                                                        Font-Size="8.5pt" ForeColor="#666666" BackColor="#F4F4F4" Text="Doc Issued Ctry :"></asp:Label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="style75">
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblDocIssuedCtryVal" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Names="Arial"
                                                        Font-Size="8.5pt" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td bgcolor="White" class="style48">
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td bgcolor="White" class="style56">
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="style71">
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                                <td bgcolor="White" class="style48">
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                                <td bgcolor="White" class="style54">
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="style73">
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                                <td bgcolor="White" class="style69">
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                                <td bgcolor="White" class="style46">
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="style75">
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                                <td bgcolor="White" class="style48">
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr id="MakerRow">
                                                <td bgcolor="White" class="style56" colspan="8">
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblTargetSignID" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10pt"
                                                        ForeColor="#4778C6" Font-Bold="True" Text="Target Signature :"></asp:Label>
                                                    &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblTSV" runat="server" BackColor="#F4F4F4" Font-Bold="True"
                                                        Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="#666666"></asp:Label>
                                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                    <asp:Button ID="btnSATS" runat="server" Text="Set as Target Signature" Width="146px" />
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                    <asp:Button ID="btnRSTS" runat="server" Text="Reset Target Signature" Width="146px" OnClientClick="ResetTargetSignID()"/>

                                                    &nbsp;
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblNote" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="8.5pt"
                                                        ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td bgcolor="White" class="style48">
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </asp:Panel>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnOK" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="GridPagerCtrl" />
            <%--thiru starts--%>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSATS" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnRSTS" EventName="Click" />
          <%-- <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnConfirm" EventName="Click" />--%>
            <%--thiru ends--%>
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div style="height: 350px; width: 995px; overflow: scroll">
                <uc1:SignatureViewGroup ID="SVSGridViewGroupBSU" EnableViewState="True" runat="server" />
                <uc1:SignatureViewGroupBSUChecker ID="SVSGridViewGroupBSUChecker" EnableViewState="True"
                    runat="server" />
            </div>
            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div style="position: absolute; left: -500px;">
                            <uc1:ImageControl id="imageCtrl" runat="server" ShowActionButton="False" Height="0px"
                                Width="0px" />
                            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="NeedKeyCheck" Value="1" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <div style="width: 86%">
        <ucGridPgr:GridPagerControl ID="GridPagerCtrl" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="MakerControlPanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnReset" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div>
                <table id="MakerTable" style="width: 70%;">
                    <tr>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblRegistration" runat="server" Text="Action For Registration" Font-Size="10pt"
                            ForeColor="#4778C6" Font-Bold="True" Font-Underline="True"></asp:Label>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="btnnormal">
                            &nbsp;
                            <asp:Button ID="btnSaveExit" runat="server" Text="Save & Exit" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="btnnormal">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnSaveSubmit" runat="server" Text="Save & Submit" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="btnnormal">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnNotify" runat="server" Text="NotifyByEmail" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="btnnormal">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnRemark" runat="server" Text="Remark" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="key">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblReceiptDate" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="lblReceiptDate" ForeColor="red"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style3">
                            <UniSign:DatePicker ID="txtReceiptDate" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="key">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblEffDate" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="lblEffDate" ForeColor="red"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style4">
                            <UniSign:DatePicker ID="txtEffDate" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="btnnormal">
                            &nbsp;
                            <asp:Button ID="btnModify" Width="60px" runat="server" Text="Modify" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="btnnormal">
                            &nbsp;
                            <asp:Button ID="btnReset" Width="60px" runat="server" Text="Reset" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="CheckerControlPanel" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div>
                <table id="CheckerTable" style="width: 77%; height: 36px;">
                    <tr>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Action For Registration" Font-Size="10pt"
                            ForeColor="#4778C6" Font-Bold="True" Font-Underline="True"></asp:Label>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="style4">
                            &nbsp;
                            <asp:Button ID="btnReject" runat="server" Text="Reject" Width="75px" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="style3">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnAccept" runat="server" Text="Accept" Width="70px" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="style5">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" Style="margin-left: 0px"
                                Width="75px" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="style6">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnNotifyMail" runat="server" Text="Notify By Email" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="style7">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnSaveNExit" runat="server" Text="Save & Exit" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="style10">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblRecDate" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="lblReceiptDate" Font-Size="9pt"
                                Font-Bold="True" Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="Black"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style9">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblEfDate" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="lblEffDate" Font-Size="9pt"
                                Font-Bold="True" Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="Black"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="btnConfirm" Width="153px" runat="server" Text="Confirm Transaction" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" id="hdnDuplicateSI" runat="Server" />
            <input type="hidden" id="hdnAction" runat="Server" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPopup" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <uc1:RegistrationRemarkPopup id="usrRegRemarkPopup" runat="server" />
            <uc1:InputDialogBox id="inputBox" runat="server" />
            <uc2:ConfirmDialogBox ID="ConfirmBox" runat="server" />
            <uc2:ConfirmDialogBox ID="ConfirmBoxReset" runat="server" />
            <uc2:ConfirmDialogBox ID="ConfirmTarget" runat="server" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Is your UserControl "confirmResetBox" is within UpdatePanel or outside? And Secondly  instead of  `<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ConfirmBoxReset" EventName="SubmitCleanup" />` try this `<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="CancelButtonID" EventName="click" />`. And if possible please upload full code so that we can give correct solution.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, thanks for your attention. confirmResetBox is outside the update panel.

Comment: using btnOK gives same error, uploaded complete code for your reference.